# How can I pass an image in the customView attribute in the LoadingIndicator?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, loading, indicator

I'm trying to create a Loading Indicator for my nativescript app and everything is working well but I wanted to add an specific image instead of the tradicional circle and for that I should (supposedly) put the image path in the OptionsCommon's customView attribute, like this:

```
    static loadingIndicator = new LoadingIndicator();
    static optionsLoading: OptionsCommon = {
        mode: Mode.CustomView,
        customView: "https://media.giphy.com/media/KbeevMxay6UneYBCAn/giphy.gif",
        margin: 10,
        dimBackground: true,
        color: '#4B9ED6',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        userInteractionEnabled: false, 
        hideBezel: false, 
        android: {
          cancelable: false
        },
        ios: {
          square: false,
        }
    };
```

Unfortunatelly it shows up a black small box instead of the image. I also tried to use a image in my comuter putting the path but still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First of all you can not use a remote image, you will have to place the image in your resources and pass the image name. Secondly GIF images are not supported by default, you will have to use plugin to display GIF images, may be [nativescript-gif](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-gif). You will have to create a GIF image view with image assigned, then pass the native instance to CustomView attribute.